# Isotope items displaying on top of each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

Here is the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/qdhw0o3a/2/

I can't understand why all the items are being displayed on top of each other? Does it have something to do with the settings? I am just using the standard settings (as far as I can tell) which should produce behaviour similar to the website.

```
$('.grid').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.grid-item',
    layoutMode: 'masonry',
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Try initiating the isotope after the window loads:

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
   $('.grid').isotope({
       itemSelector: '.grid-item',
       layoutMode: 'masonry',
   })
});
```

**Note:** Also, be on the lookout for Images Lazy-Loading in case your '.grid-item' contains images. This might interfere with isotope and make the elements come on top of each other.

Answer (score 1):

you need to give the `img` and `max-height` and `max-width`.

see the updated [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/qdhw0o3a/3/)